# jquery parent descendant selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, performance, dom-traversal

Why is 1 faster than 2?

1. `$('#p1').find('span');`
2. `$('#p1 span');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery 1.4 the selector is checked if it is an `id` selector (like your `#p1`).

- If it indeed is, the  `document.getElementId(...)` is called and result is wrapped in jQuery utility object and returned.
- If it is anything other than that, jQuery calls [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/1.) which then does whatever it does to find the elements. And, judging from the source, this is pretty non-trivial stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to test!

From this simple test:

- Content - `​<p id="p1"><span>Test</span></p>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`
- Looping 100,000 times
- Version: jQuery 1.4.2
- `$('#p1').find('span');`: 2601ms
- `$('#p1 span');`: 1998ms

It appears that the single selector is faster in this case, since you're not making as many calls through jQuery this makes sense.

[Give it a try here, look at your console](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/XAdMZ/).

---

In cae you're on jQuery 1.3.2 here's those results:

- `$('#p1').find('span');`: 3225ms
- `$('#p1 span');`: 2082ms

[Try it out with 1.3.2 here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/XAdMZ/1/).

Answer (score 0):

In your case, perhaps #1 is faster than #2, but depending on how many iterations and how many elements to search, #2 could very well be faster than #1 in other scenarios.

E.g.: I would guess if you had 3 `span` elements and no other elements in `#p1`, then #1 would be faster than #2, since find isn't trying to do as much CSS matching.  But, if you had 1000 `span` elements, along with 2000 other elements in `#p1`, I'll bet #2 would be faster, since it doesn't have to iterate over every element twice.